# Sampling and Reconstruction of digital signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sampling, nyquist, digital, reconstruction

I'm trying to write a program in Matlab that samples (using Nyquist theorem) and recovers signal. However, I cannot write sampling part for sum of 2 signal.

```
f1 = 30; 
T1 = 1/f1; 
amplitude1 = 1; 
f2 = 60; 
T2 = 1/f2; 
amplitude2 = 1; 
signal1 = amplitude1 * sin(2*pi*t/T1);
signal2 = amplitude2 * sin(2*pi*t/T2);
signal = signal1 + signal2;
plot(t, signal);
grid on;
```

I write this code.I want to draw Undersampling, sampling at Nyquist
rate and oversampling. When make researching, I find code like that, but i cannot use it for my signal.

```
fm=input('Enter the Msg frequency(fm):\n');                          
xa1=amplitude*sin(2*pi*fm*t);     
subplot(2,2,1);                 
plot(t,xa1);
```

What is fm in my signal ? How can i find it ?

```
fs1=2*fm + 10
n=0:1/fs1:1;                     
xa2=amplitude*sin(2*pi*n*fm);            
subplot(2,2,2);                  
stem(n,xa2);                     
title('Above niquist rate');
```

I want to write a code like above for all 3 cases. And how can I find the Nyquist sampling rate for signal empirically ? Thank you all. 
 [image: This is my signal]

[image: This is what i want to do]

I know signals are not same. But I just want to do same thing on my signal.

Comment: To start, for "plot(t, signal);" you haven't defined "t". I suppose you want to evaluate t at intervals, but that's not happening. Maybe you should look at another example of plotting a signal, like https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66323/how-can-i-generate-a-sine-and-cosine-function-using-an-exponential-function.

Comment: I didnt share my all code, t is defined actually. I am asking how can i make sampling on this signal.

Comment: OK, but t is "everything". I've supplied an answer that I think is what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined a sample rate, *fs*, in Hz to match your sine frequencies. The sin calculations would be in terms of normalized frequencies—*f1/f2*, for instance. Your variable *t* is the sample index, and I've defined *numSamps* as the number of samples to calculate.

```
fs = 130;       % sample rate
numSamps = 21;  % number of sample points to calculate

f1 = 30;
amplitude1 = 1;
f2 = 60;
amplitude2 = 1;

t = 0 : numSamps-1;

signal1 = amplitude1 * sin(2*pi*f1/fs*t);
signal2 = amplitude2 * sin(2*pi*f2/fs*t);
signal = signal1 + signal2;

plot(t, signal,'o');
grid on;

% overlay oversampled plot for reference
hold on;
t = 0 : .1 : numSamps-1;  % steps of 0.1 samples
signal1 = amplitude1 * sin(2*pi*f1/fs*t);
signal2 = amplitude2 * sin(2*pi*f2/fs*t);
signal = signal1 + signal2;
plot(t, signal);
hold off;
```

I've repeated the calculations at ten times the sample rate for a reference on the graph, obviously this could be done more elegantly.

Here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: This is useful for me but I have one more question. At the nyquist rate, why sampling points are not on the peaks

Comment: At the Nyquist frequency, the points would depend on phase. If you started sampling at t=0 using sine, all sample points would be 0. If you did the same with a cosine, they'd alternate at the positive and negative peaks. Of course, we need to sample at *more* than twice the frequency of the highest component to satisfy the sampling theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the simple experiment using matlab. 
https://poweidsplearningpath.blogspot.com/2020/04/ch4-adcdac-how-to-simulate-adcdac.html

---

Reconstruction is essentially a kind of interpolation or so called digital to analog conversion (DAC). Detail descriptions are introduced in chapter 4.8.3 of the DSP Bible [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3LRX.png).

However, we all understand the ideal theory. But the problem is how to **bridge the theory and practice**. Because all the signals we can simulate in Matlab is essentially 'Digital'. So, the so-cal ADC/DAC is just an approaching simulation. Let me briefly justify the difference.

[image]

**Ideal Reconstruction in DAC:** There is typically a zero order hold circuit and reconstruction filter. Please note that the frequency response of zero order hold is not evenly flat so a reconstruction filter comes to an aid.

**Matlab Simulation in DAC:** There is no need to actually simulate a zero-order hold. All you need are a up sampling and an ideal low pass filter.

Because the **t** cannot be found in the question. I just post a AD DA practice sample code here. Hope it can help.

This sample code sample a simulated 2 Hz analog signal,x_a, (with sampling rate 1500 Hz) to a discrete time signal,x_d, with 5 Hz sampling rate (nearly Nyquist rate) and then reconstruct this back,x_r.

```
%% This code simulate the AD/DA processing discussed in Chapter 4.8.3 [1]
close all; clear all;

%% parameters.
% analog
analog_fps = 1500;
analog_window_time = 3; %sec
t = 0:1/analog_fps: analog_window_time-1/analog_fps;

% digital
digital_fps = 5;
n = downsample(t,analog_fps/digital_fps);

% ADC: Quantizer
X_m = 1; % Range
B = 10;% Bit number.

%% Signal generation
freq_hz = 1; % Hz.
x_a_1 = 0.5*cos(2*pi*freq_hz*t+0.1);

% add a small high frequency component as asked.       
signal_freq = 2; %Hz
x_a_2 = 0.5*cos(2*pi*signal_freq*t+pi/2);
x_a = x_a_1 + x_a_2;

%% ADC
% Sampling
x_s = downsample(x_a,analog_fps/digital_fps);

% Quantizing (abs of input value should not over 1)
% x_d = Quantizing(x_s,B,X_m);  % A For complete ADC, a quantizing should
% be added here.
x_d = x_s; % For your case, there is no quantizing here.

%% DAC
% up sample / DAC
x_up = upsample(x_d,analog_fps/digital_fps);

% LPF (Reconstruction Filters)
h = intfilt(analog_fps/digital_fps,4,0.9); 
%% Important
% please not the parameter 0.9, ideally should be 1 for Nyquist rate.
% 0.9 here is ratio of Nyquist.
% Given known limit band signal, shourter ratio can enhance SNR by oversampling.
%  (i,e, here I filterout the freq larger than 2.5(Nyquist rate) * 0.9 = 2.25Hz)

x_r = filter(h,1,x_up);
x_r(1:floor(mean(grpdelay(h)))) = [];
x_r = [x_r zeros(1,floor(mean(grpdelay(h))))];


%% Display

figure;
plot(t,x_a);
hold on;
plot(n,x_d);
plot(t,x_r);
title('analog signal (1500Hz) v.s. digital signal (5Hz) v.s. Reconstructed signal (1500Hz)');
legend('x_a','x_d','x_r');
```

[image: Result]

You can adjust the **digital_fps** with sampling rate higher than Nyquist rate (30 for example) and 0.9 in **intfilt** to 0.5 (shorter group delay).

[image]

1. [A. Oppenheim and R. Schafer, Discrete Time Signal Processing 3rd. 2009](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh9Og.png) 
   As others have said, the book [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3LRX.png) is called the DSP bible.

Comment: No I just want to sampling on my signal in picture. I am adding one more picture what i want to do. Can u look it please ?